# How animate the title / buttons in the UINavigationBar

Tags: ios7, core-animation, uinavigationbar

I have in the UINavigationBar status information about the health of the app. It change the title text color, and one of the buttons there.

The changes work fine, but I wish to provide a smooth animation (because the status update on data changes) but don't know how. I'm not asking about moving to another views, but about how animate only the UINavigationBar titles & buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can animate those things without some extra work.

A navigation bar is a complex beast, and by default the UI objects that appear on the screen are private and maintained by the navigation bar or the current navigation item.

There should be a way to make it work however.

The current navigation item has a property titleView. normally it's nil and the navigation bar displays a title string itself. But if you plug a UILabel into the titleView property then you should be able to do animations on the animatable properties of the titleLabel.

Likewise with the bar button items.